# Are there any other useful semigroups aside from $e^{At}$

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

$e^{At}$ trivially satisfies both properties of semigroup namely

1. $T(t+s) = T(t)T(s)$
2. $T(0) = I$

Does there exist any other commonly used operators aside from $e^{At}$ that is a semigroup? Ignoring the obvious ones such as $M^{t}$ where $M \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What about $\{id, f, f\circ f,\ldots, f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f, \ldots\}$ for arbitrary $f: X\to X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. For examples, I suggest you the paper **What is a semi-group?**, by Einar Hille (page 55 of the book *Studies in real and complex analysis* edited by I. I. Hirschman, Jr.). In this paper, we read

> One encounters one-parameter transformation semi-groups in a variety of problems of analysis. We shall give some instances.
>
> 1. *Translations*: The simplest of all such semi-groups is that of translations. We take $X = C[0, \infty]$ and define
>    $$T(a)[f](u) = f(u + a),\quad  a> 0$$
>    The semi-group property is immediate.

After, the author consider other examples (involving fractional integration, harmonic functions, stochastic processes, diffusion equations and ergodic theory).

Comment: Yes, but for the translation example we have $T(t) = e^{tA}$, where $A = -\frac d{dt}$, which as Robert Israel points out, is a legitimate densely defined operator.

Comment: OK, my previous comment is incorrect.  Because with your specific Banach space, the translations are not strongly continuous.  (But I'll keep my comment there, because I think my mistake is instructive.)

Answer (score 3):

More context?  In certain situations, every one-parameter semigroup can be expressed in that way (e.g. every strongly-continuous one-parameter semigroup of bounded operators on a Banach space $X$ has an infinitesimal generator $A$, and thus can be expressed as $\exp(-At)$, where $A$ is a closed densely defined linear operator on $X$).

Comment: Where $-Ax = \lim _{t\to 0^+} (T(t)x - x)/t$.